# using spring and generating server and client in CXF

Tags: java, web-services, spring, cxf

I have created a Web Service to add two numbers and I have designed the wsdl first and then accordingly with cxf tools wsdl2java I have created the server and client and it is running successfully , Please advise and share some url which can guide how to achieve the same thing with spring in cxf 2 , using wsdl first approach.

Answer (score 2):

Using Apache CXF is quite simple and very easy to integrate with Spring.

This link provides all you need to create a service and client with Spring.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/writing-a-service-with-spring.html